# Does Contwoyto Lake empty into both Bathurst Inlet and Chantrey Inlet?

Tags: rivers, geography, canada

[Contwoyto Lake](http://goo.gl/maps/ZqBaI) is a large lake in northwestern Nunavut.  Descriptions of it say that its primary outlet leads to Bathurst Inlet.

Does the lake also have an outlet that leads to Chantrey Inlet, reaching the sea 300 miles to the east?

Comment: I vote we all go there together to check it out next summer ;-)

Comment: @gerrit and then we get complementary first class passage on well-trained and groomed llamas?

Comment: Can you find a topographic map for the area.  If so you can trace out the catchment for the lake and see if there is a topographic divide. Do you have access to a digital elevation model for the area? There are landscape analysis methods to extract the stream lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to "[Evaporation from a Small Lake in the
Continental Arctic using Multiple Methods](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.458.3927&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" *Nordic Hydrology*, 27, 1996, 1-24:

> Drainage from Contwoyto Lake occurs through the Burnside River and Back River

So, yes, to Bathurst Inlet via the Burnside River and to Chantrey Inlet via the Back River.

You can trace out the two paths on the following topo map: http://en-ca.topographic-map.com/places/Contwoyto-Lake-947046/

The Back River outlet is at the south end of the lake and flows through a series of smaller lakes.